# CM Bright with LuaTeX is different than pdftex

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, computer-modern

I am aware of this question: [General guide on how to set up font families for luaLatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237081/general-guide-on-how-to-set-up-font-families-for-lualatex), however in my use it does not solve my problem.

When I use pdfLaTeX to compile, I get:

[image]

When I use LuaLaTeX, I get:

[image]

The log returns this message: Font shape `TU/cmbr/m/n' undefined, using` TU/lmr/m/n' instead

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\ifluatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers = Uppercase,
             Ligatures = TeX,
             BoldFont  = CMU Bright SemiBold,
             ItalicFont = CMU Bright Oblique,
            ]{CMU Bright Roman}
\else
\renewcommand\bfdefault{sb} % swap bold and semi-bold
\newcommand\sbdefault{bx}
\fi

\begin{document}

\textbf{Bold Text!}
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The warning is annoying, but innocuous. The simple fact is that the CMU version of Bright is not the same as the Type1 version.

Comment: You shouldn’t load `cmbright` if you set up the main font through `fontspec`. Moving `\usepackage{cmbright}` to the `\else` block should remove the warning.

Comment: You could also add the option `NFSSFamily = cmbr` to `\setmainfont`. Again, this doesn’t get you an identical font. It suppresses a warning message.

Comment: ?? If you want to use the `cmbr` fonts under lualatex without it switching up, turn off `fontspec` and call in cmbr: `\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} \usepackage{iftex} \usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{cmbright}\ifluatex\else
\renewcommand\bfdefault{sb} % swap bold and semi-bold
\newcommand\sbdefault{bx}
\fi \begin{document} \usefont{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n} \textbf{Bold Text! \fbox{\fontname\font}} \textit{Italic Text! \fbox{\fontname\font}} \textbf{\textit{BoldItalic Text! \fbox{\fontname\font}}} \textsc{Small Caps Text! \fbox{\fontname\font}}\blindtext[1] \fbox{\fontname\font}
\end{document}`

Comment: this doesn't change the font in the caption to match it, though. nor in \maketitle. @Cicada

Comment: @Cokes Ask a separate question.

Comment: @Cokes No, it wouldn't. `cmbright` package (from 2005, using legacy fonts) needs to rewritten and updated. Looking at the log ("LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.", etc), and from the substitutions going on, I would say the package has become obsolete\broken. You can manually use the `\usefont` command everywhere (if the relevant definition files and 8-bit font files are still there). Better to use system Unicode fonts if you don't want to code up the legacy font files yourself.