# LuaLaTeX and Microtype with cmbright -- spacing and kerning

Tags: fonts, microtype, kerning

I like the `cmbright` typeface, like what `microtype` does, and love the facilities `LuaLaTeX` can offer. However, `microtype`'s `kerning` and `spacing` features are not compatible with `LuaLaTeX`. I definitely prefer the output with `pdfLaTeX` and `kerning` and `spacing`  enabled. Are there any additional packages, or ways that I can use these features with `cmbright` and `LuaLaTeX?`

MWE (I'm not well-versed in fontsettings, if you recommend any changes please do so):

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefont{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\usepackage{cmbright}  % ensure hfbright and cm-super are installed

\usepackage[%
protrusion=true,
tracking=true,
%kerning=true,  % $ NOT ALLOWED IN LUA
%spacing=true,  % $ NOT ALLOWED IN LUA
]{microtype}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are starting off with a Unicode system then `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` forces it to use legacy 8bit encoding  and legacy type1 fonts then `\usefont{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}` forces it to use a 7bit font encoding.  It is not surprising if you do not get the best out of luatex in such a case.

Comment: If you prefer to use `luatex` you should just go with it and forget about the `kerning` and `spacing` features. Neither of them really improves the output, anyway: `kerning` only makes sense for languages that require special punctuation kerns (like French), while `spacing` has been experimental from the beginning and is only half implemented, can even lead to problems.

Comment: @Robert, When I use kerning and spacing, the improvement is noticeably improved to my eyes.

Comment: Does this work better with the OpenType version of Computer Modern Bright, which is `\usepackage{fontspec}`, `\setmainfont{CMU Bright}`, `\setsansfont{CMU Bright}`?

Comment: @Davislor I've tried that in the past, but the CMU version is quite different and is less "bright" https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570877/cm-bright-with-luatex-is-different-than-pdftex

Comment: Well, in your MWE the `kerning` option does exactly nothing: it loads empty settings because it would be activated only for languages where it would make sense. The main difference with the `spacing` option is that it implicitly disables `\nonfrenchspacing`, meaning that spaces after the full stop will be equal to regular word spaces. You can easily achieve that without the `spacing` option by just adding `\frenchspacing` to your preamble.